# Specify the Samsung My Files start location

Tags: java, android, android-studio, samsung-mobile

Using the following code I can open Samsung's **My Files** file browser:

```
Intent samsungIntent= new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
samsungIntent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
samsungIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
startActivityForResult(samsungIntent, 123);
```

I have tried the following to open a specific location:

```
File root = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory( ).getPath( ) + "/myFolder" );
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(root);
samsungIntent.setData(uri);
```

I get the following message within a new activity:

> All apps associated with this action have been turned off, blocked, or
>   not installed.

**Is it possible to specify the start location of My Files Samsung file browser?**

I found the following question with no answers:

[Samsung My Files explorer: Pick file from specified folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721628/samsung-my-files-explorer-pick-file-from-specified-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set specify the startlocation in samsungIntent by specifying the FOLDERPATH like below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");    
intent.putExtra("FOLDERPATH", path);   
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);       
((Activity)Forms.Context).StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```